# Is there an enum or class in .NET containing the WebDAV http status codes

Tags: .net, http-status-codes

I have been using the [`HttpStatusCode` enumeration (msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx) to return errors in web requests, but now that I want to return a [422, "Unprocessable Entity" (webdav.org)](http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc4918.html#STATUS_422), I see that it is not among the enum's members.

I am not able to find anything in the .NET framework, and I would like to [avoid custom solutions (devio.wordpress.org)](http://devio.wordpress.com/2007/11/14/http-status-codes-in-c/) if I can help it (i.e. if something does indeed exist).

The scenario is this: The client posts a request, and validation occurs in the server. After a quick search on SO I decided that [422 is perhaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362618/proper-use-of-http-status-codes-in-a-validation-server/2657624#2657624) the [most appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290182/rest-http-status-codes/3291292#3291292), or [maybe a 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407171/which-http-status-code-to-return-when-user-provided-data-fails-validation-in-web/3407213#3407213).

So, does anyone know if  there is an enum or class in .NET 4.0 containing the WebDAV http status codes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, no such file is defined -- I had the same requirements for an API I'm building and decided to simply typecast it (which is possible with int enums) like this:

```
try {
    if (!Repository.Cancel(IdHelper.Decrypt(id))) {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Booking not found");
    }
}
catch (Exception x) {
    // typecast 422 to enum because it's not defined in HttpStatusCode
    return Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)422, x.Message);
}
```